# Can't understand example of volatile in Java specification

Tags: java, volatile, specifications

I got general understanding what `volatile` means in Java. But reading
[Java SE Specification 8.3.1.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.4) I have a problem understanding the text beneath that certain volatile example.

```
class Test {
    static volatile int i = 0, j = 0;
    static void one() { i++; j++; }
    static void two() {
        System.out.println("i=" + i + " j=" + j);
    }
}
```

> This allows method one and method two to be executed concurrently, but
>   guarantees that accesses to the shared values for i and j occur
>   exactly as many times, and in exactly the same order, as they appear
>   to occur during execution of the program text by each thread.
>   Therefore, the shared value for j is never greater than that for i,
>   because each update to i must be reflected in the shared value for i
>   before the update to j occurs. It is possible, however, that any given
>   invocation of method two might observe a value for j that is much
>   greater than the value observed for i, because method one might be
>   executed many times between the moment when method two fetches the
>   value of i and the moment when method two fetches the value of j.

How is

> j never greater than i

, but at the same time

> any given invocation of method two might observe a value for j that is
>   much greater than the value observed for i

??

Looks like contradiction.

I got `j` greater than `i` after running sample program. Why use `volatile` then? It gives almost the same result without `volatile` (also `i` can be greater than `j`, one of previous examples in specs). Why is this example here as an alternative to `synchronized`?

Comment: `never greater than` - until it overflows :)

Comment: @ZhongYu *one thread repeatedly calls the method one (but no more `than Integer.MAX_VALUE` times in all)*

Comment: There's no contradiction because the second statement is referring to how the values are *observed*, and two values can never be observed by the same thread at the same time. But I'm equally puzzled by the example in question. It doesn't seem to demonstrate anything.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers and comments. The discussion below helped me to understand the idea behind volatile much better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the point of the example is to emphasize that you need to take care and ensure the order when using volatile; the behavior may be counter-intuitive and the example demonstrates it.

I agree that the wording there is a bit obscure and it is possible to provide more explicit and clear example for multiple cases, but there is no contradiction.

The shared value is the value at the same moment. If two threads read values of i and of j at exactly the same moment, the value of j will never be observed greater than i. volatile guarantees keeping order of reads and updates as in the code.

However, in the sample, print `+ i` and `+ j` are two different operations separated by an arbitrary amount of time; hence, j can be observed larger than i, because it can be updated arbitrary number of times after the read of i and before the read of j.

The point of using volatile is that when you concurrently update and access volatile variables with the right order, you can make assumptions that are not possible in principle without volatile.

In the sample above, the order of access in `two()` does not allow to conclude with a confidence which variable is greater or equal.

Consider, however, if the sample was changed to `System.out.println("j=" + j + " i=" + i);`

Here you **can** assert with a confidence that the printed value of j is never larger than the printed value of i. This assumption will **not** hold without `volatile` for two reasons.

First, updates i++ and j++ can be executed by compiler and hardware in an arbitrary order and in reality may execute as j++;i++. If from other thread you then access j and i after `j++` but before `i++`, you can observe, say, `j=1` and `i=0`, regardless of the access order. `volatile` guarantees that this will not happen and it will execute operations in the order that is written in your source.

Second, volatile guarantees that another thread will see most recent values changed by another thread, as long as it accesses it in the later point of time after the last update. Without volatile, there can be no assumptions about the observed value. In theory, the value can stay for another thread zero forever. The program may print two zeros, zero and an arbitrary number, etc. from past updates; the observed value in other threads may be less than the current value that the updater thread sees after an update. volatile guarantees that you will see the value in a second thread after the update in the first.

While the second guarantee may seem as a consequence of the first (the order guarantee), they are in fact orthogonal.

Regarding `synchronized`, it allows to execute a sequence of non-atomic operations, like `i++;j++` as an atomic operation, e.g. if one thread does synchronized `i++;j++` and another does synchronized `System.out.println("i=" + i + " j=" + j);`, the first thread may not perform increment sequence while the second prints and the result will be correct.

But this comes at a cost. First, synhronized has a performance penalty by itself. Second, more important, not always such behavior is required and the blocked thread wastes time, reducing the system throughput (e.g. you can do so many i++;j++; during System.out).

Answer (score 5):

At any one time, then `j` is not greater than `i`.

This is different from what method two observes because it is accessing the variables `i` and `j` at different times. `i` is accessed first, and then `j` is accessed slightly later.

This isn't a direct alternative to the synchronized version because the behavior is different. One difference from not using volatile is that without volatile, values of 0 could always be printed. The increment doesn't ever need to be visible.

The example demonstrates the ordering of volatile accesses. An example that requires this could be something like:

```
volatile boolean flag = false;
volatile int value;

// Thread 1
if(!flag) {
    value = ...;
    flag = true;
}

// Thread 2
if(flag) {
    System.out.println(value);
    flag = false;
}
```

and thread 2 reads the value that thread 1 set rather than an old value.

Comment: Did you mean increments would be seen less often?

Comment: What does the spec mean by *Another approach would be to declare `i` and `j` to be `volatile`*? Another approach to what? Which problem is this solving?

Comment: In fact it doesn't print 0 even without volatile, maybe because thread cache is still fast enough. That's why it looks confusing

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to propose that it's a mistake and the examples were supposed to print `j` before `i`:

```
static void two() {
    System.out.println("j=" + j + " i=" + i);
}
```

The novelty in the first example is that, due to update reordering, `j` can be greater than `i` *even when observed first*.

The final example now makes perfect sense with some minor edits to the explanation (edits and commentary in brackets):

> This allows method `one` and method `two` to be executed concurrently, but guarantees that accesses to the shared values for `i` and `j` occur exactly as many times, and in exactly the same order, as they appear to occur during execution of the program text by each thread. Therefore, the shared value for `j` is never [observed to be] greater than that for `i`, because each update to `i` must be reflected in the shared value for `i` before the update to `j` occurs. It is possible, however, that any given invocation of method `two` might observe a value for [`i`] that is much greater than the value observed for [`j`], because method `one` might be executed many times between the moment when method `two` fetches the value of [`j`] and the moment when method `two` fetches the value of [`i`].

The key point here is that the second update will never be observed before the first update, when using `volatile`. The last sentence about the gap between the two reads is entirely parenthetical, and `i` and `j` were swapped to conform to the erroneous example.

Answer (score 2):

> How is j never greater than i?

Let's say you execute `one()` only once. During the execution of this method, i is always incremented before j as the increment operations happen one after the other.
If you are executing `one()` concurrently, each individual method call will wait for other methods in the execution queue to finish writing their values to i or j, depending on which variable the currently executing method is trying to increment. So, all writes to i happen one after the other, and all writes to j happen one after the other. And since within the method body itself i is incremented before j, at a given instant, j will never be greater than i.

> any given invocation of method two might observe a value for j that is much greater than the value observed for i, how?

If method `one()` is being executed in the background while you call `two()`, between the time when `i` is read and then `j` is read, the method one can be executed multiple times. So, when the value of `i` is read it could be the result some invocation of `one()` that happened at time t=0, and when then value of `j` is read, it could be the result of an invocation of `one()` that happened later in time, for example at t=10. Hence, `j` can be greater than `i` in this case in the `println` statement.

> Why use volatile in lieu of synchronized?

I will not list all the reasons why anyone should use `volatile` instead of a `synchronized` block. But bear in mind that `volatile` guarantees atomic access to that particular field alone, and does not ensure the atomic execution of a block of code that is not marked as `synchronized`. In this example, access to i and j are synchronized, but the overall operation {i++;j++} isn't synchronized hence it *apparently* (I use apparently since it is not exactly the same but looks similar) gives the same results as without using the `volatile` keyword.

Answer (score 2):

> How is
>
> > `j` never greater than `i`
>
> , but at the same time
>
> > any given invocation of method two might observe a value for `j` that is much >>greater than the value observed for `i`
>
> ??

The first statement is always true at any given *moment* in the program's execution, and the second statement may be true for any given *interval* in the program's execution.

When a volatile variable is written to, writes to both it and everything before it must become visible to other threads (In Java 5+, at least. The explanation doesn't really change much for versions of Java before that, though). Thus, the increment of `i` *must* be visible by the time `j` is incremented, meaning that `j` can never appear greater than `i` to other threads.

The reads of `i` and `j`, though, are not guaranteed to occur at a single moment in the program execution. The read of `i` and `j` may appear to occur very close to each other to the thread executing `two()`, but in reality some arbitrary amount of time may have passed between the reads. For example, `two()` may read `i` when `i = 5` and `j = 5`, but then get "frozen" while other threads execute, changing the values of `i` and `j` to, say, `20` and `19`, respectively. When `two()` resumes, it picks up where it left off and reads `j`, which now has a value of `19`. `two()` doesn't re-read `i` because as far as it is concerned there was no break in execution, so there is no need to undergo the extra work.

> Why use volatile then?

While both `volatile` and `synchronized` provide visibility guarantees, the precise semantics are slightly different. `volatile` guarantees that changes made to the variable will be instantly visible to all threads, while `synchronized` guarantees that changes made in its block will be visible to all threads **as long as they synchronize on the same lock**. `synchronized` also provides additional atomicity guarantees that `volatile` does not.

> Why is this example here as an alternative to synchronized?

`volatile` is a viable alternative to `synchronized` only if `one()` is executed by a single thread, which is the case here. In this case, only a single thread is ever writing to `i` and `j`, so there is no need for the atomicity guarantees `synchronized` provides. If `one()` were executed by multiple threads, `volatile` wouldn't work because the read-add-store operations that make up an increment must occur atomically, and `volatile` does not guarantee that.

Comment: The example clearly states that `one()` is executed by a single thread repeatedly, because the issue under discussion is ordering, not atomicity. What's unclear is how the example demonstrates the effect of `volatile` with regards to ordering.

Comment: @shmosel You have a point with the single thread execution. I'll fix that. As for the latter, is there a good example program that can prove `volatile`'s ordering guarantees? You can demonstrate that the ordering guarantees held for any one execution, but at least from a superficial level proving that it *always* happens without pointing to the standard (or the compiler/JIT source code) seems difficult

Comment: Take a look at @fgb's answer or [here](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/base/Suppliers.java#L110) for a real world case.

Comment: @shmosel I was more aiming for an example program that can *prove* what is said in the standard. Those are examples of `volatile` being used according to how the standard defined it, but someone less enlightened than you may argue that "Yeah, it worked *that* time, but will it work *every* time? Maybe the implementation is buggy!" That's a pointless discussion, though... In any case, thanks for your comments!

Comment: The problem of proving volatile order guarantee by a program is not even decidable, not talking tractable. So from theoretical point of view, pointing to the standard is the only way to _prove_ the volatile ordering guarantees (if it doesn't comply with standard, it is a platform bug).

Comment: In practice, you can only write various test cases to get some confidence there are no bugs (but such weird bugs do happen). volatile is supported by underlying OS/hardware and translation to these can be found in JDK sources. Regarding hardware manufacturer tests, I don't think that one can find a lot with public access. The best proof is the fact so many complex Java servers and programs do work properly and do not crash every moment.

Comment: It's not possible to absolutely prove any guarantee empirically.

Comment: @shmosel Right, which is why I was uncertain about how to address the second part of your first comment.

Comment: @FedorLosev Huh, didn't know about the undecidability of that problem, but it's not entirely unexpected given how many other things are undecidable... You raise good points though.

Comment: There's a difference between demonstrating and proving. The second example in the spec (with `synchronized`) does an excellent job at demonstrating something.

Comment: @shmosel that is right, in reality we live in Heisenberg's unpredictable world. But in this case, the problem is even harder and can not be solved even by hypothetical program in an ideal world, as shown by Rice's theorem. There are things that are provable in theory by an ideal program, like that `i=1+1` -> i==2, this one is not.

Comment: Need to note, though, decidability results do not apply directly to finite program sets we have today and undecidable becomes just intractable.

Answer (score 2):

This program does guarantee that method `two()` observes `j >= i-1` (not considering overflow).

Without `volatile`, the observed values of  `i,j` could be all over the place.

The statement

> the shared value for j is never greater than that for i

is very informal, because it means "at the same time", which is not a defined concept in JMM.

---

The core principle of JMM is about "sequential consistency". The driving motivation of JMM is

> [JLS#17](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html) - If a program is correctly synchronized, then all executions of the program will appear to be sequentially consistent

In the following program

```
void f()
{
    int x=0, y=0;
    x++;
    print( x>y );
    y++
}
```

`x>y` will always be observed as `true`. It has to be, if we follow the sequence of actions. Otherwise, there is really no way for us to reason about any (imperative) code. That is "sequential consistency".

"Sequential consistency" is an *observed* property, it doesn't have to coincide with "real" actions (whatever that means). It is entirely possible that `x>y` is evaluated to be `true` by JVM before `x` is actually incremented (or at all). As long as JVM can guarantee observed sequential consistency, it can optimize actual execution anyway it can, e.g. execute code out of order.

But this is for a singlet thread. If multiple threads are reading/writing shared variables, such optimizations of course will completely wreck sequential consistency. We cannot reason about program behavior by thinking of interleaving actions from multiple threads (with actions in the same thread following intra-thread sequence).

If we want to guarantee inter-thread sequential consistency of any multi-thread code, we must abandon the optimization techniques developed for single thread. That is going to have severe performance penalty for most programs. And it is also uncalled for -- data exchange among threads is rather rare.

Therefore, special instructions are created just for establishing inter-thread sequential consistency *when* it is needed. Volatile reads and writes are such actions. All volatile reads and writes obey inter-thread sequential consistency. In this case, it guarantees that `j >= i-1` in `two()`.

Comment: The stated problem was that *method `two` could occasionally print a value for `j` that is greater than the value of `i`*. Yet the use of `volatile` in the final example doesn't solve that problem.

Comment: It is just a short, informal explanation that `volatile` guarantees some inter-thread consistency -- which is to be defined precisely in another chapter.

Comment: I understand that the possibility of `j` being observed as greater than `i` is not a contradiction to `volatile` semantics. What I don't understand is what the example is intended to demonstrate.

Comment: It tries to say that `volatile` guarantees some ordering, compared to "normal" read/write - but not as strong as `synchronized`.

Comment: note that mutual exclusion can be entirely implemented with volatile read/write - Dekker's algorithm. So in this example, it is possible to implement the program with only `volatile` (and no `synchronized`) such that `two()` always observes `i==j`

Answer (score 0):

> This allows method one and method two to be executed concurrently, but guarantees that accesses to the shared values for i and j occur exactly as many times, and in exactly the same order, as they appear to occur during execution of the program text by each thread. Therefore, the shared value for j is never greater than that for i, because each update to i must be reflected in the shared value for i before the update to j occurs.

- this seems to clarify method one(), if **i&j** don't modified with volatile, it assumes that **i++** executed in CPU-1, but value didn't update back to physical memory unit, and **j++** executed in CPU-2 and the value immediately update back to physical memory unit. then we get the two values from memory in method two(), we will see **i** is smaller than **j**.
- but if modified with volatile, the i++(++ & update memory) like be bundled in one operation, if ++ happened, the next instruction of CPU must be the operation of updating the value of **i** back to physical memory, in this scenario, we assume that the method one() will not be executed at the gap between **"i=" + i +** and **" j=" + j**, then we try to execute method two and retrieve values of i and j from physical memory, and we will see value of **j** will never greater than **i**.

Answer (score -1):

All dependes on how you are using it. The volatile keyword in Java is used as an indicator to Java compiler and Thread that do not cache value of this variable and always read it from main memory. So if you want to share any variable in which read and write operation is atomic by implementation e.g. read and write in an int or a boolean variable then  you can declare them as volatile variable.

From Java 5 along with major changes like Autoboxing, Enum, Generics and Variable arguments , Java introduces some change in Java Memory Model (JMM), Which guarantees visibility of changes made from one thread to another also as "happens-before" which solves the problem of memory writes that happen in one thread can "leak through" and be seen by another thread.

The Java volatile keyword cannot be used with method or class and it can only be used with a variable. Java volatile keyword also guarantees visibility and ordering, after Java 5 write to any volatile variable happens before any read into the volatile variable. By the way use of volatile keyword also prevents compiler or JVM from the reordering of code or moving away them from synchronization barrier.

Important points on Volatile keyword in Java

1. The volatile keyword in Java is only application to a variable and using volatile keyword with class and method is illegal.
2. volatile keyword in Java guarantees that value of the volatile variable will always be read from main memory and not from Thread's local cache.
3. In Java reads and writes are atomic for all variables declared using Java volatile keyword (including long and double variables).
4. Using the volatile keyword in Java on variables reduces the risk of memory consistency errors because any write to a volatile variable in Java establishes a happens-before relationship with subsequent reads of that same variable.

Comment: None of this answers OP's question.

Comment: Well, that's general info I've already read. Some data race condition would be a good case for volatile usage. But why is this certain example is in specifications if it's not much different from previous ones?

Comment: He asked: "Why use volatile then?", he is not sure, why or when a volatile keyword should be used. Knowing well the concepts behind the code will help him to address his question

Comment: @humme1, I think you might want to consider the implications of "not much different" compared to "exactly the same."

Comment: 5. none of such four is quarantine of synchronisation, atomicity etc. Mamy programmers mean "volatile is exact toot to multi thread programming". NO, it isn't.